# How can you change localhost3000 to netlify client-side automatically?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, netlify

in my app client side i have a constant as **apiURL = 'http://localhost:/3000'**

when deploy it on netlify for example i have **http:/my-app.netlify.com**

so far i keep manually changing this apiURL when about to deploy and re-deploy. How can you make it recognize which end point it should have, in server side they have like process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? local 3000 : online

Comment: `const apiURL = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 'http://localhost:/3000' : 'http:/my-app.netlify.com';
` did you try this?

Comment: i haven not, i tried what you suggested for url working with backend in client side. (with localhost/8080 and heroku), works just fine! Will this works for client-side too?